# Creating a keyboard using CSS - positioning

Tags: css, html

I want to create a keyboard as seen on image:

[image]

The keys should be span objects. I have this CSS:

```
span{
height:25px;
width:25px;
float:left;
margin:0 5px 5px 0;
line-height:25px;
background-color:WhiteSmoke;
text-align:center;
font-size:14px;
border-style:solid;
border-width:1px;
border-color:silver;
}
```

... and I get this result:

[image]

It's almost OK but I don't know how to position the spans properly?

Comment: You should make a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net).

Comment: Check the width of the container that holds all these spans.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to set a width and a text-align:center on the parent element, and ditch the float

Comment: correct, we can fix that with display: inline-block for the spans, sorry I should have said that

Comment: Just a reminder, setting inline-block will create IE7 issues (as it isn't supported). If you don't care about IE7 no worries. Otherwise create some IE7 specific styles to float the spans and add left margin to the q a y keys.

Comment: Thats right, is IE7 support important to you? because If so there is a fairly simple work around

http://www.kollerat.com/cms/index.php/Web-admin/HTML/IE7-and-inline-block.html

http://blog.mozilla.com/webdev/2009/02/20/cross-browser-inline-block/